# Plotting peak positions with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a large data file in the python. I want to plot only the peak points and exclude the data points which are zero. The data file has a point recorded from the experiment and before recording the next point the zero point is also recorded. I want to exclude these data points. Here is the data file,

[data file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/62vg8xp0m16clik/data.txt?dl=0)

Here is the code I'm using

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.loadtxt("data.txt", skiprows=1, dtype=np.float64)
xData, yData = np.hsplit(data,2)
x = xData[:,0]
y = yData[:,0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.plot( x,y, 'r.', markersize=4, label=" ")
```

Here is my output
[image]

I'm expecting a exponential decay, as you can the maxima of the points show the behaviour.

Comment: Provide an example - sample input, expected output, your current output/error/state.

Comment: @skuzzy I added the output.

Comment: Have you tried boolean indexing? https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `r.`, you use markers without any connecting lines. This is basically a scatter plot, not a line plot. This, in combination with the fact that your x-values are discreet and not continuous, creates the gaps in your graph, not the zero values. You can use Boolean indexing to remove zero values, as suggested in the comments. However, removing them will not drastically change the appearance of your graph because you have so many different y-values per x-value that are smaller than the max value. Let's take a different approach and calculate the max values per x-value:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", names=["x", "y"], sep="\t", skiprows=1)

tol = 5e-3

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 6))
ax.scatter(df.x[df.y>tol], df.y[df.y>tol], s=1, label="raw data")
ax.set_ylim(0, )

max_y = df.groupby("x").max()
ax.plot(max_y.index, max_y.y, color="red", lw=4, label="max values")

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

As we can see, even setting `tol` above zero leaves many plotted dots obscuring the max image while removing actual data points for x>80. Given your data structure, you will always have with a scatter plot the appearance of a bar graph unless you make the markers so large that they fuse with the next column:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.loadtxt("data.txt", skiprows=1, dtype=np.float64)
xData, yData = np.hsplit(data,2)
x = xData[:,0]
y = yData[:,0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.plot(x, y, 'r.', markersize=8, label="only raw data")
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

But this is not advisable because the gaps are still there as we can see when we enlarge the interactive output window.

[image: enter code here]